# Como arrumo esse erro

Tags: android

Sou novo em programação para o android, eu conheço java e c#, quero apertar o botão e trocar o texto da label só consegui fazer aparecer na  toast

```
    package gabriel.meaperte;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.TextView.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void exibirmensagem(View view){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Você apertou o botão", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Aperte o botão"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.174"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:text="Botão"
    android:onClick="exibirmensagem"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502" />
```

Comment: Qual erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: Informe o erro, para que uma resposta compatível com o seu problema possa ser postada....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa localizar a view pelo seu ID dentro do seu layout, após isso setar o texto que necessita. Consulte a [documentação do google](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Segue seu código como exemplo:

```
package gabriel.meaperte;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.TextView.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity;

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Localiza a View através do seu id
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void exibirmensagem(View view){
        // Altera o valor da View      
        textView.setText("Seu novo valor no label");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Você apertou o botão", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu, Tem alguma apostila boa pra aprender android, tenho conhecimento de c# e java

Comment: No link que postei acima https://developer.android.com/training/index.html tem um treinamento, tem bastante conteúdo para começar.